# Finding last character in R using regexpr function

Tags: regex, r, character

I am having problem with finding the last character in a string. I am trying to use the `regexpr` function to check if the last character is equal to `/` forward slash.

But unfortunately it does work. Can anyone help me? Below is my code.

```
regexpr( pattern = ".$", text = /home/rexamine/archivist2/ex/// ) != "/"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a simple `grepl` function,

```
> text = "/home/rexamine/archivist2/ex///"
> grepl("/$", text, perl=TRUE)
[1] TRUE
> text = "/home/rexamine/archivist2/ex"
> grepl("/$", text, perl=TRUE)
[1] FALSE
```

Answer (score 3):

You can avoid using regular expression and use `substr` to do this.

```
> x <- '/home/rexamine/archivist2/ex///'
> substr(x, nchar(x)-1+1, nchar(x)) == '/'
[1] TRUE
```

Or use `str_sub` from the `stringr` package:

```
> str_sub(x, -1) == '/'
[1] TRUE
```

Answer (score 1):

```
^.*\/$
```

You can use this.This will fail if last character is not `/`.